# mysql stored procedures using php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure:

```
delimiter //

create procedure userlogin(in eml varchar(50))

begin

  select * from users 

  where email = eml;

end//

delimiter ;

And the php:

$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","houseDB");

$eml = "tsubi@gmail.com";

$sql = $db->query("CALL userlogin('$eml')");

$result = $sql->fetch_array();
```

The error that I get from the browser when I run the php script:

> **Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object...**

I am using phpmyadmin version 3.2.4 and mysql client version 5.1.41.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use mysqli_multi_query, not query. Check
http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php , they have a good example

Comment: Why does calling a stored procedure need `mysqli_multi_query`? He isn't creating it, he's just calling it, isn't he?

Comment: But it returns values. If it didn't, it would work as it is (actually, it's working, but in order to access result set from procedure we need to use multi_query).

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php) returns `false` if the query fails (instead of returning a result object or `true`). You need to test whether the result actually is an object:

```
$sql = $db->query("CALL userlogin('$eml')");

if (is_object($sql)) 
$result = $sql->fetch_array();
else
printf("Error: %s\n", $sql->error);
```

You will probably get an error message explaining why calling the stored procedure didn*t work out.

Comment: $sql->error will also fail because `false` has no 'error' attribute.
In case of false you can `echo mysql_error();` to debug the error

Comment: @maid450 this is `mysqli`, not `mysql`.